# Selenium WebDriver : Unable to locate link logout in Java

Tags: selenium, hyperlink

I've tried many times with xpath , csslocator ,partial link text ,
but I cant click on logout
It didn't find it

```
<a href="./ucp.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=d610c2e1bra81y37u7b2co3f4d5ac4f"><img src="./styles/Zoe/te/images/nav.gif" border="0" alt="*"> Logout</a>
```

any idea ?
Thank so much

EDIT :
[image]

Thanks and sry for no code , but it didnt't work :|

> ```
>     1) WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText(" logout"));
>     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text: logout
> ```

```
    2) WebElement link2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mode=logout')]"));
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //a[contains(@href,'mode=logout')]


3) WebElement link =  driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(" logout")); ( didn't work,return the same error)
```

> 4) WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='ucp.php?mode=logout']>[src*='cellnav']"));

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node (null) was not a DOM element

> 

Webdriver returns always this error when log in but The log in works
I can sse the account logged

> Apr 04, 2020 10:46:24 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Cookie rejected [phpbb3_n7fab_ct_cookies_test="%7B%22cookies_names%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22check_value%22%3A%2220861ca1942e42be32df5e1e9a13b9f2%22%7D", version:0, domain: .....

Comment: what did you try ! share your code .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find_element_by_link_text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text):

For example:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(' Logout')
#Or Use Xpath => find link that has certain string in one of it's properties 
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"mode=logout")]')
```

To Click on it, just call click method:

```
link.click()
```

Or use JavaScript

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link )
```